# Xdebug + KcacheGrind output graph shows percentages higher than 100%

Tags: xdebug, kcachegrind

I'm using kcacheGrind to visualize debug output of a symfony application which was saved by xdebug. I'm referring the "Call Graph" to see the execution graph and its times.

I have set the following options in kCacheGrind as follows.

- %Relative - on
- Relative to parent - on
- Cycle detection - off

Portion of my output is as follows. [image]

The problem with this is it shows the time percentages more than 100 in some classes. You can see that sfFilterChain->execute() has taken 216% of the execution time. Is this possible. What is the information which is given by that.

I have enable the cycle detection also and it didn't solve the confusion.

Can someone clarify this issue regarding the percentages of execution time. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug. Xdebug doesn't detect recursive calls properly at the moment. There is a bug for this too: http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=77 — which drastically needs attention. For Xdebug 2.3, I intend to redo most of the profiler functionality in Xdebug.

Comment: Thanks Derick and it saved my time.